# Totaling up from an array converted from a string to an integer(command line compiling)

Tags: java

I am compiling the code in command line with the following code typed in command line:

```
java aac 2 4 6 8 10
```

and I am getting the result:

> 5
>
> The number in position 0 is  2.0
>   The Sum is: 2.0
>
> The number in position 1 is  4.0
>   The Sum is: 4.0
>
> The number in position 2 is  6.0
>   The Sum is: 6.0
>
> The number in position 3 is  8.0
>   The Sum is: 8.0
>
> The number in position 4 is  10.0
>   The Sum is: 10.0

What I am trying to achieve is, for the `sum` to be the total of all the numbers divided by the amount of numbers, however for the amount of numbers there is I have come up with a length variable. For this example the length is displayed as 5 right at the start.

```
public class aac {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        // working out the length
        int length = args.length;
        System.out.println(length);

        // this is a for loop that repeats until integer i is greater than
        // integer length, which is the length of the args String array.
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            // this string equals whatever value is in position i in string array args
            String all = args[i];
            // integer numConvert now equals the integer of String all
            double numConvert = Double.parseDouble(all);
            System.out.print("The number in position " + i + " is " + " ");
            System.out.println(numConvert);
            double sum = 0;
            sum = sum += numConvert;
            System.out.println("The Sum is: " + sum);
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What you call "sum" is actually an "average" right?

Comment: check out my answer, the code is working fine. Do not forget to accept it :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you having problems creating the sum in order to calculate the average? If so, move the `double sum = 0;` out of your for loop. After the loop you divide it by `args.length` and that'll be your average.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a little amelioration of your code :

```
double average = 0.0;
double sum = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){
    String all = args2[i];
    double numConvert = Double.parseDouble(all);
    System.out.print("The number in position "+i+" is ");
    System.out.println(numConvert);
    sum += numConvert;
    average = sum / (i+1);
    System.out.println("The Sum is: "+sum);
    System.out.println("The average is :" + average);
    System.out.println();
}
```

I created 2 `double` variables outside of your `for` loop.

Each time we loop in, the current value is added to the `sum` variable to get the total sum.

Also, the `average` is changed to the value of `sum` divided by the numbers we've already seen.

Here is the output :

```
5
The number in position 0 is 2.0
The Sum is: 2.0
The average is :2.0

The number in position 1 is 4.0
The Sum is: 6.0
The average is :3.0

The number in position 2 is 6.0
The Sum is: 12.0
The average is :4.0

The number in position 3 is 8.0
The Sum is: 20.0
The average is :5.0

The number in position 4 is 10.0
The Sum is: 30.0
The average is :6.0
```